# Million of record in Array, Parse.com, IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am creating a complex app using parse as backend. My one table has approx 100000 records and I want to display all records in my UITableview.

I have created a one function to load all the table records in an array and then I populate data to UITableview. But my problem is if it's a good solution to load all the 100000 records in an array. Also I have read that parse does not allow more than 10000 record using query, so I am planing to use pagination.

Can you give me proper solution? How to handle lots of lots of table data in array and display within UITableview?

Comment: Fetch a "smart" amount of data, when you scroll, if you arrive at let's say 3/4 of your list, fetch another smart amount of data (the next ones) and append them to your array. Once you've arrive at 3/4 of your new data, fetch again, etc.

Comment: Can you give me some sort of example or link to develop this kind of scenario? thanks

Comment: Which user is going to scroll through all those items?

Comment: Admin and Normal user both.